# Using ifelse to remove unwanted rows from the dataset in R

Tags: r, subset, if-statement

I have a dataset where I want to remove the occurences of month 11 in the first observation year for a couple of my individuals. Is it possible to do this with ifelse? Something like:

```
ifelse(ID=="1" & Month=="11" and Year=="2006", "remove these rows",  
  ifelse(ID=="2" & Month=="11" & Year=="2007", "remove these rows",   
         "nothing"))
```

As always, all help appreciated! :)

Comment: There are likely many good answers to this question, all of which would benefit greatly from having a reproducible example.

Comment: How many individuals are you removing? 2 or 3, or more? (If it's more you should use `%in%`).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You don't even need the `ifelse()` if all you want is an indicator of which to remove or not.

```
ind <- (Month == "11") &
           ((ID == "1" & Year == "2006") | (ID == "2" & Year == "2007"))
```

`ind` will contain a TRUE if `Month` is `"11"` and if either of the other two subclauses is `TRUE`.

Then you can drop those sample using `!ind` in any subset operation via `[` or `subset()`.

```
dat <- data.frame(ID = rep(c("1","2"), each = 72),
                  Year = rep(c("2006","2007","2008"), each = 24),
                  Month = rep(as.character(1:12), times = 3))
ind <- with(dat, (Month == "11") & ((ID == "1" & Year == "2006") |
                                    (ID == "2" & Year == "2007")))
ind
dat2 <- dat[!ind, ]
```

Which gives

```
R> ind
  [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
 [13] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
 [25] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
 [37] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
 [49] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
 [61] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
 [73] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
 [85] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
 [97] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
[109] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
[121] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
[133] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
R>     dat2 <- dat[!ind, ]
R> nrow(dat)
[1] 144
R> nrow(dat2)
[1] 140
```

which is correct in terms of the example data/

Answer (score 2):

A `data.table` solution, which will be time and memory efficient (and *slightly* less coding). It will scale well for *big* data sets.

If the columns were integer, not factor

```
library(data.table)
DT <- data.table(ID = rep(1:2, each = 72),
          Year = rep(2006:2008, each = 24),
          Month = rep(1:12, times = 3))
# or you could use:   DT <- as.data.table(dat)
setkey(DT,ID,Year,Month)
DT[-DT[J(1:2,2006:2007,11),which=TRUE]]
```

Comment: Thanks for the heads up -- was struggling with character/factor and `-J(...)`

Comment: Ah, I didn't notice the character/factor aspect. If `DT`'s columns are type character, then : `DT[-DT[J(c("1","2"),as.character(2006:2007),"11"),which=TRUE]]`.  If they are factor, then that'll work too (with warning I think) or as factor: `DT[-DT[J(factor(1:2),factor(2006:2007),factor(11)),which=TRUE]]`.