# how to join datasets separated by midnight

Tags: r, join, time-series, aggregate

Please, help.
Imagine I have records (let’s say numbers) collected every hour during a week (24 hours x 7 days).  I’d like to analyze and compare data, collected during the night hours only. The problem is that what we accept as night belongs to two consecutive dates separated by midnight. I can split nights and days based on sunrise and sunset data, creating new column (with two level factor “day” & “night”) but how to “explain” to R that evening from October  1 has to be combined with morning October 2, not from the morning October 1 (what R does based on similar date)? Let’s mark this whole night (in new column)as the next day. I mean that night between Oct1 and Oct2 could be marked as "Oct2" for example. And the script i plan to apply to the rather big data set. Last column is what i would like to get. The whole night (evening of Oct1 and morning Oct2) marked as Oct2. So next night (evening Oct2 and morning Oct3) has be be marked as Oct3. I hope i explained what i'm striving to.
Thanks!

Sorry,guys. It's definitely looks odd, but following the advice i have copied the output of R of what i have right now and at the bottom you will find of what i would like to get.

numbers period            datetime             sunrise              sunset
1        1    day 2017-10-01 18:00:00 2017-10-01 05:05:00 2017-10-01 21:49:00
2        4    day 2017-10-01 19:00:00 2017-10-01 05:05:00 2017-10-01 21:49:00
3        1    day 2017-10-01 20:00:00 2017-10-01 05:05:00 2017-10-01 21:49:00
4        3    day 2017-10-01 21:00:00 2017-10-01 05:05:00 2017-10-01 21:49:00
5        9  night 2017-10-01 22:00:00 2017-10-01 05:05:00 2017-10-01 21:49:00
6        8  night 2017-10-01 23:00:00 2017-10-01 05:05:00 2017-10-01 21:49:00
7        8  night 2017-10-01 00:00:00 2017-10-01 05:05:00 2017-10-01 21:49:00
8        2  night 2017-10-02 01:00:00 2017-10-02 05:07:00 2017-10-02 21:47:00
9        7  night 2017-10-02 02:00:00 2017-10-02 05:07:00 2017-10-02 21:47:00
10       3  night 2017-10-02 03:00:00 2017-10-02 05:07:00 2017-10-02 21:47:00
11       6  night 2017-10-02 04:00:00 2017-10-02 05:07:00 2017-10-02 21:47:00
12       4  night 2017-10-02 05:00:00 2017-10-02 05:07:00 2017-10-02 21:47:00
13       5    day 2017-10-02 06:00:00 2017-10-02 05:07:00 2017-10-02 21:47:00
14       3    day 2017-10-02 07:00:00 2017-10-02 05:07:00 2017-10-02 21:47:00
15       6    day 2017-10-02 08:00:00 2017-10-02 05:07:00 2017-10-02 21:47:00
16       2    day 2017-10-02 09:00:00 2017-10-02 05:07:00 2017-10-02 21:47:00
17       7    day 2017-10-02 10:00:00 2017-10-02 05:07:00 2017-10-02 21:47:00
18       1    day 2017-10-02 11:00:00 2017-10-02 05:07:00 2017-10-02 21:47:00
19       8    day 2017-10-02 12:00:00 2017-10-02 05:07:00 2017-10-02 21:47:00
20       8    day 2017-10-02 13:00:00 2017-10-02 05:07:00 2017-10-02 21:47:00
21       9    day 2017-10-02 14:00:00 2017-10-02 05:07:00 2017-10-02 21:47:00

```
numbers;period;datetime;sunrise;sunset;night
1   day 01.10.2017 18:00    01.10.2017 5:05 01.10.2017 21:49    oct1
4   day 01.10.2017 19:00    01.10.2017 5:05 01.10.2017 21:49    oct1
1   day 01.10.2017 20:00    01.10.2017 5:05 01.10.2017 21:49    oct1
3   day 01.10.2017 21:00    01.10.2017 5:05 01.10.2017 21:49    oct1
9   night   01.10.2017 22:00    01.10.2017 5:05 01.10.2017 21:49    oct2
8   night   01.10.2017 23:00    01.10.2017 5:05 01.10.2017 21:49    oct2
8   night   01.10.2017 0:00 01.10.2017 5:05 01.10.2017 21:49    oct2
2   night   02.10.2017 1:00 02.10.2017 5:07 02.10.2017 21:47    oct2
7   night   02.10.2017 2:00 02.10.2017 5:07 02.10.2017 21:47    oct2
3   night   02.10.2017 3:00 02.10.2017 5:07 02.10.2017 21:47    oct2
6   night   02.10.2017 4:00 02.10.2017 5:07 02.10.2017 21:47    oct2
4   night   02.10.2017 5:00 02.10.2017 5:07 02.10.2017 21:47    oct2
5   day 02.10.2017 6:00 02.10.2017 5:07 02.10.2017 21:47    oct2
3   day 02.10.2017 7:00 02.10.2017 5:07 02.10.2017 21:47    oct2
6   day 02.10.2017 8:00 02.10.2017 5:07 02.10.2017 21:47    oct2
2   day 02.10.2017 9:00 02.10.2017 5:07 02.10.2017 21:47    oct2
7   day 02.10.2017 10:00    02.10.2017 5:07 02.10.2017 21:47    oct2
1   day 02.10.2017 11:00    02.10.2017 5:07 02.10.2017 21:47    oct2
8   day 02.10.2017 12:00    02.10.2017 5:07 02.10.2017 21:47    oct2
8   day 02.10.2017 13:00    02.10.2017 5:07 02.10.2017 21:47    oct2
9   day 02.10.2017 14:00    02.10.2017 5:07 02.10.2017 21:47    oct2
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [R: Add day/night column to data frame, when sunrise/sunset times change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36915565/r-add-day-night-column-to-data-frame-when-sunrise-sunset-times-change)

Comment: No, it's not. i have no prob to add sunrise and sunset data (what i did and you may see it in my example) and based on this i added column "period". But i would like to see the distribution of my numbers during consecutive nights over a long period. Thanks!

Comment: you can add three columns, 1. sunrise of the first day , 2. sunset of that day , 3. sunrise of the next day,
I think this may help you.. when you want to choose 'night' tag you should compare 'the time' to the 'next day sunrise'

Do you mean this?

Comment: You know I don’t add columns of SS or SR manually. I’ve just merged tabs (datatab and tab with SR & SS over the year) based on date. Even if I see how to add another column of SR with date shifted for one day, I still have no idea how to use it to solve my task. It has to be some logical vector, false or true, but I failed to create the conditions for such task. It’s rather simple for our mind but how to do this for R? 
Something like here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12459169/using-ifelse-to-remove-unwanted-rows-from-the-dataset-in-r

Comment: If the data of the previous night (“period”==night) is just 1 day earlier, then mark it the same date. But only if the time of that data is later then noon. Somethin like this

Comment: Please provide your data in a reproducible format, i.e. `dput()`. Please read the R tag description for more information. You should also show your desired output.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [merge two daily time series after summarising on shifted hours](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46164588/merge-two-daily-time-series-after-summarising-on-shifted-hours)

Comment: Could you provide the link where i may read about dput()? Sorry about inconvenient

Comment: write 'dput(data)' in RConsole... then copy the resulting structure here...
'data' would be your data in your environment